# Regex to find the text between certain code

Tags: php, regex

my text is like this;

```
[name]JAAN JOHN[/name]
[cell]09178656469[/cell]
[city]Dhaka[/city]
```

I want to get text in between each of the above `[ ]` quotes using regex. Please pardon me since I searched alot this site but unable to get my required answer. Please help!

**EDITED:**

For example, I want to get the result like this:

```
Name: JAAN JOHN
Cell #: 09178656469
City: Dhaka
```

How to get this result?

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: I'm really sorry sir! but I'm very new to regex. I can write code with PHP but its hard for me to write regex. Please help

Comment: You say "between each of the above `[ ]`". I suspect you don't mean that; you mean between each of the `[tag]` and `[/tag]` pairings, right? e.g. you want to extract "JAAN JOHN"

Comment: Yes, you are right Utkanos. I meant this

Comment: It would help everyone (also future readers) to give an example output (what you want to get).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use back reference and get the matched group from index 2. In below sample code I am interested in `cell` tag

```
\[(cell)\](.*?)\[\/\1\]
```

Here is [demo](http://regex101.com/r/dV4fE6/10)

---

If you are interested in all tags of **matching end tag** then try

```
\[(.*?)\](.*?)\[\/\1\]
```

Here is [demo](http://regex101.com/r/dV4fE6/11)

Get the desired tag name from index 1 and value from index 2.

sample code:

```
$re = "/\\[(.*?)\\](.*?)\\[\\/\\1\\]/";
$str = "[name]JAAN JOHN[/name]\n[cell]09178656469[/cell]\n[city]Dhaka[/city]";

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

Comment: This is the first time in many years that I have seen backreferences used. That is *very* cool! ;)

Comment: I've updated my first post, please read again, Thank you for your time sir!

Comment: Thank you sir! Your answer have solved my question, I'll select your answer as the best one.

Thanks for all others.

Answer (score 1):

This regex will do for each line.

```
\[[^\]]+\](.*?)\[\/[^\]]+\]
```

Test the regex [here](http://regex101.com/r/zN9uV4/2).

Comment: I've updated my first post, please read again, Thank you for your time sir!

Answer (score 1):

Use [Lookahead and Lookbehind Assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

```
((?<=]).*(?=\[\/))
```

See [**this demo**](http://regex101.com/r/pT1iV9/1)